# Windows Service is getting stopped with an error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am very new bie to the C# world, Because of my one project I need to create one Window service where I have to call a Web Service and do some operation and create a log for it. Firstly, I have created a windows application and run the Application and it worked, But same thing when i am trying to do in Windows Service(C#) The Service is getting started but its getting stopped throwing an error as :

> Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at FMIWebService.FMInteractWebService.ConfirmValidConnection(RequestInfo reqInfo, String state, Boolean checkWorkplaceSurveyApp) at FMIWebService.FMInteractWebService.GetData(RequestInfo reqInfo) at SyncInvokeGetData(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dis...

My service.cs file is :

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {


        //Write Logs
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);

        doWork();

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 10000; 
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void doWork() {

        FMsystemcall obj = new FMsystemcall();
        DataSet tickets = obj.FMAPICall("FM_SP_DOVEVIVO_TICKET_PULL","","FALSE","REQNO");
        for (int i = 0; i < tickets.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 35; i++)
        {
            string reqno = tickets.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REQNO"].ToString();
            DataSet isss = obj.FMAPICall("FM_SP_DOVEVIVO_TICKET_PULL", reqno, "TRUE");
            WriteToFile("IDFM:-" + isss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IDFM"].ToString());
            WriteToFile("STATUS:-" + isss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString());
            WriteToFile("MESSAGE:-" + isss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Message"].ToString());
            WriteToFile("\n");
        }
    }
```

Any help will be highly Appreciated!!

Comment: It says right there in the log that you have an attempt at a null-dereference in `FMIWebService.FMInteractWebService.ConfirmValidConnection`. If it's not obvious to you why/where it happens, add code there along the lines of `if (someVar == null) throw new Exception("Check 1");`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError tried It didnt worked. Any more suggestion?

Comment: There's a problem in your ConfirmValidConnection function. Can you post it please?

Comment: There is no function named ConfirmValidConnection. This all function which i am calling here is from webservice.

Comment: Debugging Services is somewhere betweeen impossible and Painfull. One comon workaround I saw was debugging them in a console Application. Confining it to there gives you a decent UI to work with.

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal: If there was no such function, it would not be in the stacktrace. Hence there **is** such a function. You are using 3rd party classes/code, so it is foolish to claim they do not have those functions. If you can not see it, it might simply be a private/internal one. The designer of that code propably just failed a proper documentation/early checking. It happens: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: Do not do `doWork()` in `OnStart()`. Just kick off your service on a seperate thread and return.